# python convert dict values to correct data types

Tags: python

I have a dict of strings:

```
{'a': '12345', 'b': 'something', 'c': '192847.2134', 'd': '-21374.123', 'e': '-1239', 'f': 'something else'}
```

The actual values should be a mix of strings, ints, and floats rather than strings:

```
{'a': 12345, 'b': 'something', 'c': 192847.2134, 'd': -21374.123, 'e': -1239, 'f': 'something else'}
```

I want to be able to convert them reliably to their respective data types but I'm not sure what the fastest and most reliable way would be. It would be great if I could have some sort of JSON string that maps each key to its data type:

```
{
  "a": "int",
  "b": "str",
  "c": "float",
  "d": "float",
  "e": "int",
  "f": "str"
}
```

but I'm not sure if that's possible, because reading that in will just result in strings rather than the actual data types .

I don't particularly want to loop over and run a try/except on every key (unless that really is the best way). I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-represents-a-number-float-or-int), but not sure if it's the best way or not. Is there something obvious to resolve this?

[edit] This is part of a specification I know ahead of time.

Comment: Why do you need to store your type mapping as JSON?  Why can't you just use the dictionary you want this to represent?

Comment: "but I'm not sure if that's possible, because reading that in will just result in strings rather than the actual data types ." Do you need to "read it in"? Can it be part of the code? **How do you know** that a specific key should have its value converted to a particular type? Is that just part of a specification that you know ahead of time? Or do you want the user to tell you, when the code is run, to use specific types for specific keys? Or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it is part of a specification that I know ahead of time.

Comment: The question here is whether you know in advance what types certain specific keys should be converted to. If you do, then @Rahul's excellent answer will solve your problem. However, I suspect that you want to [try to] determine the most appropriate type by inspecting the string values

Comment: "it is part of a specification that I know ahead of time" Then write it into the code, and use the actual types rather than string names, as in Rahul's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, Write a mapping function and just iterate through and call corresponding functions.

```
d = {'a': '12345', 'b': 'something', 'c': '192847.2134', 'd': '-21374.123', 'e': '-1239', 'f': 'something else'} 
mapping = {
  "a": int,
  "b": str,
  "c": float,
  "d": float,
  "e": int,
  "f": str
}
result = {key:mapping.get(key)(value) for key,value in d.items()}

# Out
{'a': 12345,
 'b': 'something',
 'c': 192847.2134,
 'd': -21374.123,
 'e': -1239,
 'f': 'something else'}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rather infer the types and convert them to what is most appropriate and if your dict looks as your write, ie. one key, one value, you can also use pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'a': '12345', 'b': 'something', 'c': '192847.2134', 'd': '-21374.123', 'e': '-1239', 'f': 'something else'}

pd.DataFrame([my_dict]).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').convert_dtypes().to_dict(orient='records')[0]
```

that will give you:

```
{'a': 12345,
 'b': 'something',
 'c': 192847.2134,
 'd': -21374.123,
 'e': -1239,
 'f': 'something else'}
```

and if you stopped before converting back to dict and checked the types:

```
a      Int64
b     string
c    Float64
d    Float64
e      Int64
f     string
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know. Although in my case I do know in advance, I was curious about this as well

Answer (score -1):

You can use `literal_eval` which will convert strings to their data type like typing them literally in python.

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

You can use it to convert the strings and if you need build the dict with types.
Note: that literal_eval supports and only supports native python types, from bytes to dicts.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, because the values that should remain as strings *don't look like* "typing them literally in python" - i.e., they don't contain enclosing quote marks.